# Noetherian schemes and varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

What types of varieties (e.g. projective, affine,...) over a field $k$ (char = $0$) are Noetherian schemes?

Comment: Anything of finite type, but the converse is not true. (Take a transcendental field extension.)

Comment: According to the old joke, a variety is defined as a separated integral scheme of finite type over a field. So as Zhen Lin points out, it's always Noetherian.

Comment: The comments above already answer your question. Here's a more general statement. Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme. If $Y\to X$ is a finite type morphism of schemes, then $X$ is noetherian. (To answer your question: take $X$ to be the spectrum of a field...)

Comment: @user64687: Why did you mention the definition of variety as 'the old joke'?

Comment: What definitions of variety and Noetherian scheme are you using? A Noetherian scheme is defined to be one covered by finitely many affine noetherian schemes, which are spec of a noetherian ring. Then it is trivial to ask if an affine variety over $k$ is noetherian, because it covers itself, and by definition it is spec of a finitely generated $k$ algebra. All projective schemes are noetherian because projective space has a standard finite affine open cover.